# asl_send doesn't display in xcode-Windows-Devices?

Tags: xcode

I write code:

```
asl_object_t client = asl_open(NULL, "com.apple.console", 0);
asl_log(client, NULL, ASL_LEVEL_WARNING, "%s","test");
```

It can display in xcode-Windows-Devices.

but write:

```
asl_object_t client = asl_open(NULL, "com.apple.console", 0);
asl_object_t asl_msg = asl_new(ASL_TYPE_MSG);
asl_set(asl_msg, ASL_KEY_MSG, "asl test output");
asl_send(client, asl_msg);
asl_free(asl_msg);
```

It donesn't display in xcode-Windows-Devices.

Comment: asl_set(asl_msg, ASL_KEY_LEVEL, "4");      is    ok

Comment: I notice you don't set the level with the 2nd code fragment?  The whole ASL interface seems retarded to me; I generally avoid it.